# Where does Creed Bratton from The Office actually live?

Tags: the-office

In Season 5 - Episode 08 "Frame Toby" Creed mentions that he lives by the quarry. But in a deleted scene from Season 3 - Episode 03 "The Coup" it is revealed that creed lives in the office. Dwight says Michael could charge rent from Creed since he might be living here and then Creed clarifies to the documentary crew that he sleeps under his desk 4 days a week and for 3 days he goes to Toronto.

But then in the final episode of the show we see Creed been living in the office presumably for a long time.

So where has Creed lived all his life? Has he been constantly shifting from office to a house by the quarry to his actual place in Toronto or has he simply lived in one place and these are just his bluffs.

Comment: Well, he seem to be actually homeless so he does not have a regular place. I'm also convinced he is not reliable in general and oftens throws nonsense, weird info about himself.

Comment: Final episode was when Creed was trying to evade police, so it kinda makes sense that he was living somewhere weird.

Comment: Pretty sure Creed is an extraterrestrial.